# Scan a second line from a file

Tags: c

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I want to scan the second line with fgets. How may I do so? How do I scan specific lines from a file?

Comment: You could using something lower than `fgets` such as `open`, `read`, and `seek` to get to the position you are interested in. However, for this example you could simply just use `fgets` twice to scan the second line of input you are interested in.

Comment: Files do not contain any explicit information about "lines". "Lines" are simply bunches of characters separated by newline characters, and in order to find these you will have to scan these one by one, either directly or indirectly by using functions such as `fgets` as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to jump to a specific line directly. However, you can create a function which reads the file from the beginning until it finds a certain number of newline characters, so that the file position will be at the start of that specific line once the function returns:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// This function returns true on success, false on failure
bool go_to_nth_line( FILE *fp, int line_num )
{
    //jump to start of file
    if ( fseek( fp, SEEK_SET, 0 ) != 0 )
        return false;

    //loop until the required number of newline characters was found
    for ( int i = 1; i < line_num; i++ )
    {
        char buffer[4096];

        //continue reading until newline character is found
        do
        {
            if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, fp ) == NULL )
                return false;

        } while ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL );
    }

    return true;
}
```